# Уникальная ссылка для автоматической авторизации PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день!

Нужна помощь в таком вопросе:
Есть функционал личных сообщений на сайте, после каждого сообщения приходит пользователю уведомление на email. С этого сообщения можно нажать на ссылку "прочитать", которая ведет на диалог на сайте. НО проблема в том, что если у пользователя закончилась сессия, то его просто будет перекидывать на 404 ошибку.

Вопрос в следующем: как правильно сделать БЕЗОПАСНУЮ ссылку, чтоб в случае разлогивания юзера на сайте он автоматом залогинился. 
Мне не нужно готовое решение, мне хотелось бы узнать, кто как делал, чтоб обезопасить систему, может быть, ссылка должна быть 1-разовая, после перехода она ставала неактивной?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Делал подобное. Генерируется ссылка (в моём случае было 50 символов латиница (верхний и нижний регистры) и цифры). Записывалась в базу с указанием, кому было отправлено (id пользователя). После перехода по ссылке запись из БД удалялась. Так как известен почтовик пользователя, то дополнял проверку реферера. Отправив письмо пользователю на *user*@gmail.com, получить переход с пустым реферером или с мейлру было бы странно. В дальнейшем собирался подключить проверку куки и сравнивать ip-адреса. Большинство пользователей заходит с одного или нескольких постоянных адресов, что позволило бы увеличить урвоень идентификации. Но проект закрыли, и всё ушло в архив.

Answer (score 1):

Для этих целей действительно делаются одноразовые ссылки! Хранить их можно в отдельной таблице, связав с пользователем, к примеру, 'tokens'. При логине таким образом токен обнуляется! А при отсылке сообщения генерируется заново.  + задавать время жизни.

Comment: ИМХО: Не советую проверять рефер... у многих стоят почтовые клиенты! и переход осуществляется не с web-интерфейса (Это к ответу от terantul..)

Comment: Проверка как один из вариантов для подтверждения.

Answer (score 0):

Писать некий ключ в базу, который будет давать доступ, либо же составить функцию генерации этого ключа, + ответ выше.